# When I insert a Word file as an object into PowerPoint, the macros in the Word file no longer work

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint, activex, embedding

I need help please. I'm trying to embed a Word file containing macros into a PowerPoint presentation that will be distributed to several people, but once it's inserted as an object in PowerPoint, and i open the object, the Word macros don't work at all.

Do you have any idea why? And how can I keep my macros functional?

This is the VBA Code in my ActiveX button from my word file :

```vb
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CopierTextePressePapier
    MsgBox "Vous avez bien copié le code pour le batiment PRINCIPAL", vbInformation, "Confirmation"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In an environment that has the `Block macros from running in Office files from the Internet` Group Policy setting enabled for Microsoft Office applications, macros in embedded files are blocked from running.

For example, you may receive the following security notice:

```
Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern.

Macros in this document have been disabled by your enterprise administrator for security reasons.
```

To work around the issue, save the embedded or the original Office file to a trusted location.

For more information about the `Block macros from running in Office files from the Internet` Group Policy setting, see [New feature in Office 2016 can block macros and help prevent infection](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2016/03/22/new-feature-in-office-2016-can-block-macros-and-help-prevent-infection/).

Comment: I didn't receive any security notifications, but I had an idea. I uploaded my Word file to OneDrive with a direct link to download the file in my ppt, and it works !

Thanks for your help !